# Add a panel to application (specifically Ellie Mae Encompass) via plugin.

Tags: c#, panel

I am looking to add a rightpanel menu to the Encompass application to show additional data while in a loan. I had a friend give me the following code as a starting point, but I'm getting lost (not sure if I'm missing references, etc.). I'm a pretty novice programmer looking at code from someone much much better than me. So any help in getting this to work would be appreciated!

```
using System;
using EllieMae.Encompass.ComponentModel;
using EllieMae.Encompass.Automation;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace RightPanel
{

    [Plugin]
    public class RightPanel
    {
        private Form mainForm;
        private TabControl _tabs;
        private bool _created;
        private Panel rightPanel;


        public RightPanel()
        {
            EncompassApplication.Login += new EventHandler(EncompassApplication_Login);
        }
        private void EncompassApplication_Login(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                if (form.Text.ToLower().Contains("encompass"))
                {
                    mainForm = form;
                }
            }

            Control[] controlArray = mainForm.Controls.Find("tabControl", true);
            if ((uint)((IEnumerable<Control>)controlArray).Count<Control>() <= 0U)
                return;

            _tabs = controlArray[0] as TabControl;
            _tabs.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(SelectedIndex_Changed);
        }

        private void SelectedIndex_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_tabs.SelectedIndex < 0)
                return;
            TabPage tabPage = _tabs.TabPages[_tabs.SelectedIndex];
            if (tabPage != null && (tabPage.Name.Contains("loanTabPage")))
                BindToRightPanel();
        }

        private void BindToRightPanel()
        {
            if (_created)
                return;
            Control[] controlArray = mainForm.Controls.Find("rightPanel", `enter code here`true);
            if (((IEnumerable<Control>)controlArray).Count() > 0)
            {
                rightPanel = controlArray[0] as Panel;
                CreateMenu();
            }
        }

        private void CreateMenu()
        {
            if (mainForm == null)
                return;

            RemoveControlById(Settings.MainMenu, rightPanel);
            RemoveControlById(Settings.MenuButtonPanel, rightPanel);

            MenuButton menuButton = GetMenuButton("Open Loan Tools", "MtgMenuButton");
            menuButton.BackColor = Color.White;

            MenuPanel = new MenuPanel(Settings.GetMenu(), menuButton);
            MenuPanel.Name = Settings.MainMenu;
            MenuPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Right;

            Panel panel = new Panel();
            panel.Name = Settings.MenuButtonPanel;
            panel.Width = 27;
            panel.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
            panel.Controls.Add((Control)menuButton);

            rightPanel.Controls.Add((Control)MenuPanel);
            rightPanel.Controls.Add((Control)panel);
            _created = true;
        }

        private List<MenuPanelSection> GetMenu()
        {
            return new List<MenuPanelSection>()
      {  new MenuPanelSection(Utilities.GetHeading("Loan Information"), Utilities.HighestWeightedPersona() == "Loan Officer", new Control[1]
        {
          (Control) new LoanInformation()
        })
      };
        }

        private void RemoveControlById(string controlID, Panel panel)
        {
            Control[] controlArray = panel.Controls.Find(controlID, true);
            if ((uint)((IEnumerable<Control>)controlArray).Count<Control>() <= 0U)
                return;

            for (int i = 0; i < ((IEnumerable<Control>)controlArray).Count<Control>(); ++i)
                controlArray[i].Parent.Controls.Remove(controlArray[i]);
        }

        private MenuButton GetMenuButton(string buttonText, string buttonName)
        {
            MenuButton menuButton = new MenuButton();
            menuButton.AutoSize = true;
            menuButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            menuButton.FlatStyle = 0;
            menuButton.Height = 100;
            menuButton.Name = buttonName;
            menuButton.VerticalText = buttonText;
            menuButton.Width = 27;

            return menuButton;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you give some more information on what is not working? Is it failing to compile?

Comment: Yes, it is failing to compile. I'm getting errors beginning in the CreateMenu() class. Some of it is I'm not sure if I'm referencing everything that I need to. I was told just System.Windows.Forms, but not sure where items like "Settings", "MenuPanel" etc are coming from (it's telling me they don't exist in this context)

Answer (score 1):

This line of code appears a couple times in your sample above:

```
Control[] controlArray = mainForm.Controls.Find("rightPanel", true);
```

The Controls.Find function only takes one parameter, the name of the control you are looking for and it only returns that control if it is found, not an array of controls.

Changing the above line to this will correct that problem.

```
Control control = mainForm.Controls.Find("rightPanel");
```

Ellie Mae provides is own form objects and controls to be used in side the application. Remove the reference to the System.Windows.Forms and add:

```
using Elliemae.Encompass.Forms;
```

I haven't tried running the code, this is what I found looking through the sample you provided. If you have more specific errors I might be able to help you through them.